# Javascript and Css file is not loading while using proxy_pass of Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have an angular application (say admin app) running at **port 4200** in my windows machine. My **Nginx** is running at port 8080. When request is coming at Nginx I am forwarding it to my angular application (admin app, **port 4200**) but in that case Js and Css files are not rendered for the admin app and showing **404 error** for all css/js files.

> My operating System is **windows 10**

Here is my configuration at nginx.conf file:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
    
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;    

    server {
        listen       8080 ;
        server_name  localhost;
        
        location  /admin {
           proxy_pass   http://localhost:4200/; 
        } 

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

[here is the error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ebv8T.png)